# How to access properties of the 3d Viewport?

Tags: python, scripting, 3d-view

I've just started trying to write a script to speed up my workflow in Blender, but I'm having trouble interpreting the Python commands that show up when you hover the cursor over a button.

For example, I want to toggle the "*Limit Selection to Visible*" button in *Edit Mode*, but keep getting errors. If I click the button, the log/output window shows:

```
bpy.context.space_data.use_occlude_geometry = True
```

But if I type this into the console, it gives me an error (see screenshot).

[image]

Looking at the [Blender API provides some information](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_78c_release/bpy.types.SpaceView3D.html#bpy.types.SpaceView3D.use_occlude_geometry), but not enough for someone with my limited amount of scripting experience.

Just taking the python line from the log window and pasting that into the console works for some things, but not others. Any ideas why?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Operators* and *properties* are often context sensitive. It means they need to be executed from specific context (screen area). Your example needs to be run from [`View_3D`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Area.html?highlight=view_3d) context, so it cannot run from the *Python Console*.

Luckily, there is a way to access different screen areas and get their [`types`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Area.html#bpy.types.Area.type) and properties. In your case [`use_occlude_geometry`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.SpaceView3D.html#bpy.types.SpaceView3D.use_occlude_geometry) is a property of [SpaceView3D](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.SpaceView3D.html#bpy.types.SpaceView3D), thus only accessible from that [space](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Space.html):

```py
for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        if bpy.context.active_object.mode == 'EDIT':
            area.spaces[0].use_occlude_geometry = not area.spaces[0].use_occlude_geometry
```

You can paste and run the above example in *Python Console* as a multi-line command or run it from the *Text Editor* as usual.

---

However, best practice for [Addons](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/info_tutorial_addon.html) is writing your own [Operator](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/info_quickstart.html#operators-tools) to match the context:

```
import bpy

class OccludeGeometryToggle(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Toggle Occlude Geometry Option in 3D View"""
    bl_idname = "view3d.toggle_occlude_geometry"
    bl_label = "Occlude Geometry Toggle"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object.mode == 'EDIT'
    
    def execute(self, context):
        context.space_data.use_occlude_geometry = \
            not context.space_data.use_occlude_geometry
        return {'FINISHED'}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(OccludeGeometryToggle)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(OccludeGeometryToggle)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Once the operator is registered, press <kbd>Space</kbd> in *Edit Mode* (since the [poll()](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/info_quickstart.html#operator-poll) method checks whether the [active object](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.context.html?highlight=active_object#bpy.context.active_object) is in the correct [mode](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.mode)) and type `"Occlude Geometry Tog..."`.

---

Note that the code above used to work till Blender 2.79. Since version 2.8+, the property `use_occlude_geometry` was removed from the API. A similar effect can be achieved by the property `shading.show_xray` -- it's not exactly the same thing though, because it also makes grid lines peek trough the object.

Comment: Very helpful Miki, thank you. I had no idea about the context-specific bit. Makes a lot more sense now.

Comment: It is also possible to [override the context](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/6105/935) used by any existing operator.